# Help understanding CART trees notation

Tags: cart, mathematical-statistics

I was reading the Decision Trees user guide of sklearn to understand some of the underlying mathematics behind trees. Everything was fine until I stumbled upon some notation I'm not understanding. This is what appears in the documentation:

[image]

(link to the documentation can be found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree))

My problem is I have no idea how to interpret or even read Q_left and Q_right. Is this some set theory specific notation? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The tree is splitting the data to reduce the error, Q is the data, Q left is the data that goes in the left node, Q right is the data that goes in the right node. The first line is saying that Q left is defined by xj being less than or equal to tm, which is the hypothetical best split. Q right, as Wayne said, is everything else, AKA where xj > tm.

Comment: For more information about notation...$Q_{left}$ is defined using [set builder notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) and $Q_{right}$ is defined using the [set difference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you literally don't know what $Q_{left}$ means or how to pronounce it, or do you mean what the right-hand sides mean?

In term of the right-hand sides, the $|$ appears to mean a conditional, so $Q_{left}$ is the set of (x,y) pairs such that $x_j <= t_m$ The backslash in $Q_{right}$ appears to be the set complement: $Q_{right}$ is elements of $Q$ not including the elements of $Q_{left}$.

EDIT: I changed the backslash operator name to the more correct "complement". Wikipedia describes here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)

Comment: It was about the right hand sides. Most time when you read the notation out loud is quite easy to understand what it means. I didn't know about set substraction notation (even though it was kind of evident based on what Qleft  and Qright are. Thanks a lot !